# emacs unable to create frame in tty mode on linux `No applicable method: frame-creation-function`

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs, crash

Recently I'm unable to open emacsclient in tty mode, it always fails with the below error (environment redacted, and added newlines)

```
*ERROR*: No applicable method: frame-creation-function, (
(menu-bar-lines . 0) 
(tool-bar-lines . 0) 
(vertical-scroll-bars) 
(bottom-divider-width . 1) 
(right-divider-width . 1) 
(client . #<process server <4>>) 
(environment ...)  
(window-system) 
(tty . "/dev/pts/2") 
(tty-type . "screen-256color")
)
```

Any suggestions on what to debug?

Comment: some details about which version of Emacs you're using will help. Also, how *exactly* are you trying to start `emacsclient`, and how did you start the server/daemon? If you start emacs via `emacs -Q`, then start the server, can you then open `emacsclient --nw`?  I can't reproduce the problem here with Emacs 28.0.50.

Comment: Just a wave to say I'm getting the same issue with emacsclient -nw with 28.0.50.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm getting the same problem with `emacsclient -t` on Emacs 28.0.50, native compilation, pgtk, as well. I do *not* get the issue if I start emacs as `emacs -Q --daemon` and then `emacsclient -t`, so it's definitely in our configuration; I'm guessing it has something to do with `default-frame-alist`.